# Jenkins throwing error Errno 2] No such file or directory for chrome driver path when running a selenium job

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, subprocess

Running a simple selenium job on jenkins(jenkins is running in a docker container on an azure server instance) throwing error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver'

File "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Historical Volume 
Job/cronjobs/extractCookies.py", line 34, in extract_cookie
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 105, in start
    self._start_process(self._path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 207, in _start_process
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver'
```

I have checked the file do exist in the location. This is happening just on jenkins but working fine on my local system. This is what jenkins is passing to the python's subprocess module subprocess.Popen cmd ['/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver', '--port=47841']

Comment: One thing to note is that Jenkins runs with its own Jenkins user (and not your local account). Try doing a `ls -lrt` before the command to see if the file actually does exist from Jenkins point of view. If it does, then check the permissions to see if the Jenkins user has permission to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `playwright` instead of `selenium`. `Playwright` is one of the newer python libraries for web browser automation.

Install it like this: `pip install playwright`, and install browsers:

`playwright install`, and once you run this command, chromium, webkit, and firefox will be downloaded. Don't worry, you can still use chrome and msedge! Just need to add an argument into the code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="chrome") #allows usage of chrome
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com')
    page.locator('button#example').click() #clicks button called 'example'
    browser.close()
```

This will work, *without a webdriver*. Note that `playwright` runs in headless mode by default, so you'll need to switch the argument to false when launching the browser in order to see the browser opening.

In addition, if you're using chrome or msedge, use the line: `browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="chrome or msedge")`, but if you're using another browser, do away with the channel argument and just say: `browser = p.firefox.launch()`, I used firefox for an example.

`Playwright` is a much better python library for web browser automation, without needing a webdriver, and being one of the newer python libraries, it certainly has its advantages, especially since it works with other popular programming languages other than python.

Playwright Documentation: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro